# is an idiot for talking to you like that

Tags: prepositions, clauses, reasoning

> a. He is an idiot for talking to you like that.

> b. He is angry for having been mistreated.

> c. He is exhausted for working hard.

I think (a) is perfectly natural.

(b) seems to work, but is not natural, and (c) is basically incorrect?

Do you agree with that assessment?  Is there any reason why (c) doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes your assessment is fine. (c) is wrong and should be

> He is exhausted *after* working hard.